# calling a method of an object at instance creation

Tags: php, object

In PHP why can't I do:

```
class C
{
   function foo() {}
}

new C()->foo();
```

but I must do:

```
$v = new C();
$v->foo();
```

In all languages I can do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you can't call an arbitrary method on a freshly created object like `new Foo()->someMethod();`

Sorry, but that's the way it is.

But you could build a work around like this:

```
<?php
class CustomConstructor
{
  public static function customConstruct($methodName)
  {
    $obj = new static; //only available in PHP 5.3 or later
    call_user_method($methodName, $obj);
    return $obj;
  }
}
```

Extend CustomContructor like this:

```
class YourClass extends CustomConstructor
{
  public function someCoolMethod()
  {
    //cool stuff
  }
}
```

And instantiate them like this:

```
$foo = YourClass::customConstruct('someCoolMethod');
```

I have not tested it but this or something like it should work.

**Correction: This will only work in PHP 5.3 and later since late static binding is required.**

Comment: See the manual section for call_user_method for more about this.

Comment: Also PHP 6 will not have that?

Comment: I don't know if this issue will be fixed in PHP6. Anyway it's still a long time until 6 comes out.

Answer (score 16):

Starting from PHP 5.4 you can do

```
(new Foo)->bar();
```

Before that, it's not possible. See

- [One of many question asking the same on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189988/inline-class-instantiation-in-php-for-ease-of-method-chaining)
- [Discussion on PHP Internals](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg44923.html)
- [Another Discussion on PHP Internals](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-general@lists.php.net/msg229008.html)
- [Relevant Feature Request in BugTracker](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34502)

But you have some some alternatives

Incredibly ugly solution I cannot explain:

```
end($_ = array(new C))->foo();
```

Pointless Serialize/Unserialize just to be able to chain

```
unserialize(serialize(new C))->foo();
```

Equally pointless approach using Reflection

```
call_user_func(array(new ReflectionClass('Utils'), 'C'))->foo();
```

Somewhat more sane approach using Functions as a Factory:

```
// global function
function Factory($klass) { return new $klass; }
Factory('C')->foo()

// Lambda PHP < 5.3
$Factory = create_function('$klass', 'return new $klass;');
$Factory('C')->foo();

// Lambda PHP > 5.3
$Factory = function($klass) { return new $klass };
$Factory('C')->foo();
```

Most sane approach using [Factory Method Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) Solution:

```
class C { public static function create() { return new C; } }
C::create()->foo();
```

Answer (score 8):

From PHP 5.4 you CAN do: `(new Foo())->someMethod();`

Answer (score 1):

You should not be able to execute code like

`new C()->foo();`

in other languages, at least not as long as that language accurately follows logic.  The object is not just created using `C()`, but with the full `new C()`.  Therefore, you should hypothetically be able to execute that code if you include another pair of parentheses:
`(new C())->foo();`

(Be warned: I haven't tested the above, I'm just saying it *should* hypothetically work.)

Most languages (that I've encountered) deal with this situation the same way.  C, C#, Java, Delphi...

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. php is not c, c#, java, delphi etc.

Comment: Hm, odd.  I really could have sworn I've done this sort of thing in PHP before.  Oh well!

Comment: Not true. Based on an operator precedence table new an () are first executed. Also other languages works the same way. So in Java, C#, etc if you do new C().foo() all go fine!

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and was successful -

```
<?php

$obj = new test("testFunc");

class test{
    function __construct($funcName){
        if(method_exists($this, $funcName)){
            self::$funcName();
        }
    }

    function testFunc(){
        echo "blah";
        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This fails to achieve the chain-ability the asker was intending through the question. Your implementation also requires that the constructor functions parameters be used explicitly for call the chained funciton, which is not what the constructor should be doing.