# purpose of braces around class initiation

Tags: php

```
    {
      public function handle() : string{
        if(!array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)) {
          return (new Login)->handle();
        }
      }
    }
```

hi everybody, just started to learn php and i wonder, why (new Login)->handle() is working just fine, but if i remove braces like this - new Login->handle() - my code editor alerts me that "return type must be a string", althrough nothing change in "handle" method and it's himself returns a string

Comment: It's because PHP allows class instances with empty constructor args to be created with or without `()`, ie `new Login;` is the same as `new Login();`. The problem with the former is that `ClassName->method()` is not valid. The latter is though... `new Login()->handle()`. Wrapping the `(new Login)` turns it into a self-contained expression

Comment: I'm not getting the same error message.
I get: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "->", expecting ";""

With `return (new Login)->handle();` and if `$_SESSION` has the 'username' key, I get:
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Other::handle(): Return value must be of type string, none returned"

Answer (score 1):

its more of a syntax thing, since normally you would write:

```
    {
      public function handle() : string{
        if(!array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)) {
          $login = new Login;
          return $login->handle();
        }
      }
    }
```

But you can bypass assigning the newly constructed object to a variable by:

```
    {
      public function handle() : string{
        if(!array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)) {
          return (new Login)->handle();
        }
      }
    }
```

Might be related: [Create objects on the fly without variable assignment with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567481/create-objects-on-the-fly-without-variable-assignment-with-php)

Without the braces, it outputs "return type must be a string" because php thinks that you're trying to "return" an object of instance "Login"

Comment: crystal clear explanation, thank you