# Are there PHP librabries which extend builtin types to ease method chaining?

Tags: php, extension-methods, built-in, primitive

PHP definitely has no issue letting one define custom classes which ease method chaining like `$some_entity->filter(predicate = fn($n) => $n===42)->transform()->show()`.

But what about built in types like array, integer and string? [Componere](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.componere.php)  provides an API for composition of classes, monkey patching, and casting. And [Runkit7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit7-method-add.php) also enables to alter classes. Thus said altering primitive types to turn `[1,2,3]->last()` into a valid PHP code might be more complicated.

All the more, with the `__call` function, it’s possible to add many proxy methods, [as exemplified in ArrayObject documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#Hcom107079)

Given these are probably well known, are they some libraries out there that already leverage on these facilities to perform common operations, like the previous one, or `"1,2,3"->split(",")`?

## Related resources

- ["Inline" Class Instantiation in PHP? (For Ease of Method Chaining)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189988/inline-class-instantiation-in-php-for-ease-of-method-chaining)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject
- https://www.npopov.com/2014/03/14/Methods-on-primitive-types-in-PHP.html
- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class-like_primitive_types

Comment: You could make a `v` function, which looks at the type, then loads associated prototypes, i.e `v("1,2,3")->split(",")`, split could use a private value

Comment: Yes, sure, although this is not what I’m looking for. :)

Comment: https://florian.ec/blog/chain-better-arrays-in-php/

Comment: That looks very interesting, thanks @dqhendricks. Please add it as an answer along a direct link to the official/github project page. 

Comment: https://github.com/sebastiaanluca/php-pipe-operator seems to be in the same vein.